# Fatal error running scrapy in Anaconda: Unable to create process

Tags: python, scrapy

Installed Anaconda today, run `conda install -c conda-forge scrapy` to install it, with no apparent issues. If I try to use any scrapy commands, however, I get a "Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process", with the right path for scrapy, but the wrong one for python.exe.

`where python` finds the correct path. The `%PATH%` variable includes said directory. I tried installing within a virtual environment, with no difference in result. Not quite sure what to do, now.

Previous questions from other users received no valid answers:

[How to fix "Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using *path*/scrapy.exe" in anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57307710/how-to-fix-fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using-path-scrap)

This is marked as a duplicate, but it's a different question from the original and doesn't have a functional solution.

[Getting error: Fatal Error Installing Scrapy tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57237304/getting-error-fatal-error-installing-scrapy-tutorial)

This suggests installing with pip, which I'd rather not, but may fall back to if necessary.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do consider posting the _actual error message_, since details matter

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel It was exactly the same as the one in both the included links, except for the path to scrapy. Ended up installing via pip, as the second user did.